# setting up a subdomain to point to a folder using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

hi guys I've build a website using the zend framework and using clean urls - however I need to set up a subdomain such that it points to only one folder on my website i.e I want the subdomain `admin.mysite.com` to point to `mysite.com/admin` and I wanna do it using my htaccess file

EDIT -------

This is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|htm|html)$ index.php 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ admin/$1 [L]


AddType text/css .css
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this above your existing URL rerwites:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ admin/$1 [L]
```

**Edit:** To prevent it from being interpreted as a Zend Frameowrk controlleradd the following above your existing `RewriteCond`s to prevent it from transforming your admin URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
```

And I think that should take care of everything.

**Edit:** Your `.htaccess` file should look more like the following, though I don't *think* any of the changes would relate to your 403 error, but maybe we'll get lucky. If not, I'll keep thinking of what might cause that.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Don't rewrite requests on admin subdomain to the Zend Framework handler
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^admin
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|htm|html)$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ admin/$1 [L]

AddType text/css .css
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

Comment: I don't want the admin folder to be treated as a controller - actually my admin panel is a different application so I wish it to run independantly. My old host had a real simple panel to create subdomains but on my new host I have to write up in an htaccess file :(

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I've updated the answer now, you can try that and see if it works.

Comment: I got a 403 error for some weird reason? my admin folder is in my public_html folder...

Comment: And your `.htaccess` file is in your `public_html` folder, right?

Comment: yes exactly.. its working fine for everything else.. lemme show the htaccess file

Comment: I've updated my answer now, see if that solves anything (it does fix a few potential problems, but I'm not confident it fixes the problem you're having right now)

Comment: hmmmmm ok I'm getting this error now:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: Very weird. Do you have access to the server logs? Maybe they'll provide a little more insight on exactly what's being requested so we can figure out why it's giving you that 403 error.

Comment: Sorry for the late update - ok now my subdomain is working BUT its not pointing to the admin folder for some weird reason? instead its pointing to the website root :( and looks a mess

Comment: I made an update just to be safe, but I don't think it's related. I'll keep thinking of what the issue might be and hopefully I'll come up with something. I know this works on my test server, so there must be something I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

On admin.mysite.com "/" you can symlink to "/admin"

Answer (score 0):

on subdomain admin.mysite.com use directive Redirect.

```
Redirect permanent / http://mysite.com/admin
```

Or you can use proxy:

```
ProxyPass / http://mysite.com/admin
ProxyPassReverse / http://mysite.com/admin
ProxyPreserveHost on
```